# Pipeline issue while installing Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1

Tags: xdb, sitecore-commerce, pipelines

I am trying to install Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1 with Sitecore 8.2 (initial release 160729). I am following the instruction at [Sitecore Commerce SDN](http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreCommerce/DeploymentGuide/en-us/index.html). After I install Commerce Server 11.4.153 using exe, I start adding modules and update packages on Sitecore instance as mentioned in the documentation. The list of modules and packages are as below and are installed in same order as given:
Modules:

1. Sitecore Commerce Connect 10.3.27
2. Sitecore.Commerce.Habitat.Images-1.0.0
3. Adventure Works Images

Update Packages:

1. Sitecore Commerce Server Connect.10.3.52
2. Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.1.3.153
3. Sitecore Commerce Business Tools Shared.1.3.13
4. Sitecore Commerce Merchandising Manager.11.1.48
5. Sitecore Commerce Customer and Order Manager.1.3.11
6. Sitecore Commerce Pricing and Promotion Manager.1.3.17
7. Sitecore.Reference.Storefront.Common.10.3.158
8. Sitecore.Reference.Storefront.Powered.by.SitecoreCommerce.10.3.158

It works well till the 7th package is installed, I can see the updates in backend, but as soon as I install `Sitecore.Reference.Storefront.Powered.by.SitecoreCommerce.10.3.158` update package, it shows error and whole site breaks. I am then not even able to log in or even see front end site. Error is as below:

> Could not load type
>   'Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.RemoveContactPiiSensitiveData.RemoveContactPiiSensitiveDataProcessorBase'
>   from assembly 'Sitecore.Analytics, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. Description: An unhandled exception occurred
>   during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>   originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.RemoveContactPiiSensitiveData.RemoveContactPiiSensitiveDataProcessorBase'
>   from assembly 'Sitecore.Analytics, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.

Have anyone faced this issue or know what is the possible cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message it is clear that RemoveContactPiiSensitiveData Pipeline is not able to load from Sitecore.Analytics. If you search about this, you will come to know that this pipeline is related to right to be forgotten as per General Data Protection Act enforced by EU from 25th May 2018.

To be compliant with this, Sitecore in its Update 7 for Sitecore 8.2(180406), have added few extra pipelines so that websites can trigger the pipeline to remove contact information in someone needs to be forgotten. Details can be read from the [Release notes](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/82/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2082%20Update7/Release%20Notes). As per that, it is mentioned

> To enable an organization to implement the Right to be forgotten, a new removeContactPiiSensitiveData pipeline has been implemented.

So I was using the latest release of Sitecore Commerce 8(Update 3) with Initial release of Sitecore 8.2 where as I needed Sitecore 8.2 Update 7. This was causing all the trouble.